# getting error that nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to hibernate and I have a query

```
 select * from Losa_App a
 inner join 
     os_historystep os
 on
     a.app_ref_no = os.ref_id
 where 
     os.step_name = '011' and app_status = 'R' or  app_status = 'S' ;
```

when i run this query on sqldeveloper it runs and give me the results. Now i translated the query into HBL like

```
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer();
    List<String> lstObj = new ArrayList<String>();
    query.append(" from ");
    query.append(getClassName());
    query.append(" a inner join "
            // + WflWorkflowHistoryStep.class.getName()
            + " OS_HISTORYSTEP os with a.appRefNo = os.ref_id "
            + "where os.step_name = '011' and a.appStatus = 'R' or a.appStatus = 'S'  ");

    List<LosaApp> result = null;

    try {

        result = getHibernateTemplate().find(query.toString());
        if (CollectionUtils.isNotEmpty(result) {
            return result;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {

        String message = e.getMessage();
        System.out.println();

    }

    return null;
```

But when this query runs i get exception that

```
nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for
join! [ from com.thetasp.losa.data.LosaApp a inner join  OS_HISTORYSTEP os with
a.appRefNo = os.ref_id where os.step_name = '011' and a.appStatus = 'R'
or a.appStatus = 'S'  ]
```

Why i am getting this error ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your HQL syntax is wrong.

1. You need to specify the alias by using the keyword `as`. E.g:- **Losa_App as a**
2. If you give `inner join`, and have your association mappings done, then you needn't provide the `on` clause.
3. If you want to give `a.app_ref_no = os.ref_id`, then you need not specify `inner join`. Hibernate will take care of that.

For more info, do have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068597/inner-joins-query-in-hql).